# direction rtl css for input not working properly in Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have set `direction=rtl` in input text, but in Safari and Chrome the cursor 
always stays to the left side and in other browsers the cursor stays to the right side.

```css
input{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
```

Why is this not working in Safari and Chrome?

Could it be a CSS issue?

Comment: read this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Comment: @sumit i read this article, text is come from right-to-left but the problem of cursor position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
function rtl(element)
{   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" onkeyup="rtl(this);">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" onkeyup="rtl(this);">
```

**Click Here** [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/uqwjx27t/)